# Relink a shared library to a different version of libc

Tags: c, linker, ld, libc

I have a linux shared library (.so) compiled with a specific version of libc (GLIBC2.4) and I need to use it on a system with different version of libc. I do not have sources for the library in question so I cannot recompile for the new system. Is it somehow possible to change the dependencies in that library to a different libc?

Comment: I take it you need to make it run against an *older* version of glibc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the .so on a system with an older glibc, you would need the source code and recompile/relink it with the older glibc. The alternative is to install the required glibc on the old system in a non-default location and adjust the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the executable that needs this .so

If there's a newer glibc rather, it should normally not be a problem as glibc tend to be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your library really uses interfaces that changed (unlikely), you can just hexedit the references to versions in the resulting `.so` file. They're all text anyway.

Comment: Very hackish, as is the question. I didn't know that the references were all text.

Comment: The GLIBC_... version strings are not all text, if you change them to a lower version in the binary, the symbol still wouldn't work.

Comment: They are text. They're in the `.dynstr` string table just like the strings for symbol names to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do is compile the old glibc version for your system and then build your application with that glibc and your shared library. Ugly though ...